# Overloading of virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, overloading

I was asked this question in an interview. I was not able to answer this there. Neither am I able to get it now, as to why the output is the way it is.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun ( int x = 0)
    {
        cout << "Base::fun(), x = " << x << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun ( float x = 10.0 )
    {
        cout << "Derived::fun(), x = " << x << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Derived d1;
    Base *bp = &d1;
    bp->fun();
    d1.fun();
    d1.fun(1.2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Base::fun(), x = 0
Derived::fun(), x = 10
Derived::fun(), x = 1.2
```

The problem is:
In the first case we say that both the fun() functions get overloaded (and not overridden since they differ in their declarations) and the base fun() gets called, but it is not possible for these declarations of fun() to be overloaded (since they differ only whether the declaration contains default argument or not)

```
void fun(int x = 0)
void fun(float x = 10.0)
```

It is not possible for these functions to get overloaded.

There seems to be a contradiction in both the above cases.

Any related article/ link explaining the situation would be highly helpful.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be and why?

Comment: In the first case the output should be,Derived::fun(), x = 10.0, due to run time polymorphism. In the second and third case, how do you decide the output?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++, for a member function to override a base class function, the argument types have to exactly match the base class function's argument types. Since the base class function takes in an `int` and your derived class's function takes in a `float`, it's not considered an override. You can see this by using the `override` keyword:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun ( int x = 0)
    {
        cout << "Base::fun(), x = " << x << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void fun ( float x = 10.0 ) override // Doesn't compile!
    {
        cout << "Derived::fun(), x = " << x << endl;
    }
};
```

What's happening in your code is that C++ considers your function to be an *overload* (another function with the same name) rather than an *override*. Let's look at this code:

```
Derived d1;
Base *bp = &d1;
bp->fun();
```

Here, since the line `bp->fun()` uses a call through a base class pointer, C++ looks in `Base` to see which function to call. It finds `Base::fun(int)`. Now, since that function is marked `virtual`, it will call `Base::fun(int)` unless something overrode it. But since there isn't an override, `Base::fun(int)` ends up getting invoked.

So what about these later two lines?

```
d1.fun();
d1.fun(1.2);
```

Here, since you're calling these functions on objects of static type `Derived`, C++ tries to find a function called `fun` in the `Derived` class. It finds your new function `Derived::fun(float)`, and due to the way C++ does name lookup in classes it does not look in the base class to find `Base::fun(int)`. Therefore, both of these calls are treated as calls to `Derived::fun(float)`, so there's no ambiguity about which function to call when no arguments are presented. The compiler never even looked in the `Base` type because there was no need to.

So, to summarize:

- You've introduced an *overload*, not an *override*. Using the *override* keyword would help you diagnose issues like this in the future.
- Calling `fun` through the base pointer looks for a function named `fun` taking in an `int`, since the base pointer's `fun` function takes in an `int`. That finds the version in `Base` because there's no oerride.
- Calling `fun` through the derived object looks for a function named `fun` starting in `Derived`, and it finds your override.

Comment: In the first case, why run time polymorphism is not there?

Comment: @YamanSingla Just updated the answer to explain what's going on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @templatetypedef. I understood now what is going on actually!

Comment: In the second and third case, function overloading is not possible (since the function definitions differ only in whether default argument is present or not) , but since as you said in your answer that in the first case, the functions get overloaded (and not overridden). Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: @YamanSingla Can you explain why function overloading isn't possible?

Comment: @YamanSingla Oh, I think I see what you're saying. The way C++ does name lookup here works list this. First, it looks at the static type of the receiver object to determine where to start looking. (Here, that's `Derived`). It then looks at the name of the function you're calling (here, `fun`) and looks for a match. Since it finds a function named `fun` inside of `Derived`, it stops looking for other matches. (There's a quirk in C++ where the base class is never searched for an overload if a name is found in a derived class). Therefore, it finds `Derived::fun(float)` and uses that.

Comment: Since they differ only whether the declaration contains default argument or not. See this http://ideone.com/oFKZPf

void fun(int x = 0)
void fun(float x = 10.0).

Comment: OOPS in C++!! There are lots of rules and exceptions! BTW please merge your comment with your answer. Thanks again!